# Flutter does not recognize valid imports

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this simple Flutter app.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Sample'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column (
            children: <Widget>[
              CustomCard(mainTitle: "A simple widget!"),
            ]
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String mainTitle;

  CustomCard({@required this.mainTitle});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 48,
      width: 200,
      child: Text('$mainTitle'),
    );
  }
}
```

If I move the `CustomCard` class into another file, e.g. custom_card.dart, and then do `import 'package:myproject/custom_card.dart'` I get the error message: `"The parameter mainTitle is not defined"`. If the class `CustomCard` is left within main.dart everything works.
What am I missing?

Here is my setup.
Flutter 1.2.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8661d8aecd (3 weeks ago) • 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
Engine • revision 3757390fa4
Tools • Dart 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb) • 
Windows 10 64x

Answer (score 3):

`package:myproject/custom_card.dart` is a reference to `lib/custom_card.dart` under the package root. You also need to ensure that the `myproject` portion matches the package name in the `pubspec.yaml` file. See https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout#public-libraries